# Wide format CSV with Plotly Express

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

I have a wide csv file that where the first column is the date (in `Y-m-d` format) and following columns, with headers are different covid19 related indicators, like in this example:

| data | casos_novos_t | casos_novos_d | obitos_t | obitos_d |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-21-04 | 123000 | 12000 | 34000 | 345 |
| 2021-22-04 | 134000 | 14000 | 34505 | 567 |

and so on. The sample dataset can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gKI2ZlgXcE4FA04Do8W5GU9K5XIbkDXU/view?usp=sharing)

I have the following code in Python:

```
# Import Libraries

import pandas as pd 
import plotly.express as px 

# Read CSV file 

df = pd.read_csv("covid19pt_data.csv")

# Plot

fig = px.bar(df)

fig.show()
```

After running it I get the following error message:

**ValueError: Plotly Express cannot process wide-form data with columns of different type**

If I change my code to

```
fig = px.bar(df, x='data',y='novos_casos_t')

fig.show()
```

the code works, showing me a bar graph for that column. The same for any other column.

However, after reading **[this post](https://plotly.com/python/wide-form/)** I was under the impression that plotly now supports wide format frames so I don't understand what I'm clearly doing wrong.

My experience level is close to zero and any help in making me understand what I'm doing wrong is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you scroll down to the section on [Wide-Form Defaults in Plotly](https://plotly.com/python/wide-form/#wideform-defaults), they explain that if you don't provide the parameters `x` or `y` for the `px.bar` method, then the default behavior is to set x to `df.index` and y to `df.columns`. However, your DataFrame is not indexed by date, and your date column `data` is the first column in df.columns

If we look at `df.dtypes` for your DataFrame:

```
data             object
casos_novos_t     int64
casos_novos_d     int64
obitos_d          int64
obitos_t          int64
d_internados      int64
d_uci             int64
recuperados_t     int64
recuperados_d     int64
vigilancia_t      int64
vigilancia_d      int64
ativos_t          int64
ativos_d          int64
```

We can see that the columns are not the same data type because the `data` column is an `object` type while the others columns are `int64`, and since df.columns is passed to the `y` parameter by default, this is what is causing Plotly express to throw `ValueError: Plotly Express cannot process wide-form data with columns of different type`

If you want to use this default behavior to plot all of the numerical columns against the `data` column in a bar chart, you can set the index of your DataFrame to the `data` column using `df = df.set_index('data')`. This ensures that the remaining columns in your DataFrame are of the same `int64` type.

```
# Import Libraries

import pandas as pd 
import plotly.express as px 

# Read CSV file 

df = pd.read_csv("covid19pt_data.csv")

## set the index as the data column
## all of the remaining columns are now of the same int64 type
df = df.set_index('data')

# Plot
fig = px.bar(df)

fig.show()
```

[image]